# Apollo Client subscribeToMore and updateQuery behaviour for updated vs new records

Tags: apollo-client

It looks like `subscribeToMore`'s callback `updateQuery` behaves differently depending whether the inbound record is already existing in the client cache.  That is, for new records (as in *every* example on the web) you are required to return a new version of the cache based on `previous` and `subscriptionData`.  Great for manually merging new records into the local cache.

BUT, if the inbound record already exists (by id), the new record is *instantly* merged and there is nothing `updateQuery` callback can do about it. `updateQuery` is still called, but the *new* data comes into updateQuery already merged into the `previous` parameter.

Ideally, I’d like to modify inbound records in the case of insert or update.  Any ideas?